# Find value of a in $ a^2 + \sqrt{a} = 18 $.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve for $a$ if $ a^2 + \sqrt{a} = 18 $.
I have already tried using formulae but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: If $\sqrt a=b, a=b^2\implies b^4+b-18=0$

Clearly, $b=2$ is a solution

Comment: Velcome to the site!

Answer (score 5):

The polynomial $x^4+x-18$ factorizes to
$$(x-2)(x^3+2x^2+4x+9)$$
so $x=2$ is its only positive root. Since $a=x^2$ is positive, there are no more solutions.

Answer (score 0):

How about $a=4$               ?

Comment: Is that the only solution?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee it seems this must be the only real solution; note that $f(a) = a^2 + \sqrt a$ is monotonically (strictly) increasing over the domain $a \geq 0$.